# Iterate through a Dictionary List in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to iterate through, and grab values off a dictionairy that is populated through a call to sharepoint using the ListServiceUtility.GetListItemData Method. My code looks as follows

```
actualList = ListServiceUtility.GetListItemData(Test_Sharepointsite_url, myCred, Test_List_Name, Nothing, fieldNames, <Query/>, isRecursive, pagingSize)

For Each Entry As Dictionary(Of String, String) In actualList

            Debug.WriteLine(cnt)
            cnt += 1

            For Each pair In Entry
                Debug.WriteLine(innerCnt)
                innerCnt += 1
                Debug.WriteLine("Key:" & pair.Key & " Value:" & pair.Value)
            Next
        Next
```

cnt goes up to 4, as I expected it should, seeing as there are 4 entries in my sharepoint list, however, innerCnt doesn't increment at all, and the last for each block there is completely by passed.

I'm not getting any errors, so it's a logic problem here, not a syntax one. Hopefully i've provided some one here with enough information to help!

Comment: Maybe the dictionaries are empty?

Comment: I have to agree with Magnus here.  Can you debug and check what "Entry" in your outer loop?  The logic looks fine to me.

Comment: The only explanation is that the dictionaries are empty ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionaries were empty because of the feildname variable being improperly created. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments, it appears that the inner loop is not being accessed - can you step through the code in debugger to check.

Also, in VB variables in loops do not reset to 0 so innerCnt will contain the total number of times through the loop, not the number of times through for each Entry. If this is not what you want you will need innerCnt=0 just before the inner loop.

Note: This is by design but it is the oposite behavior from C#.